# After enabling Calendar the Next/Prev buttons are off to the side

Tags: views, 7, datetime

How can I get these two buttons in a better place to make them useful?  Currently they reside overlapping the sidebar and calendar almost right in the middle of it.  I've looked at documentation and I can't figure it out. I'm using drupal 7.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS is your friend.  Find the id and/or class of these offending buttons and override their positioning in your theme.

Comment: I can't find the css files that have the div references in them.  Do you have any idea where its at? I searched my CSS files under modules and did not find it.

Comment: I would look in the theme directory of your calendar module.  There should be all kinds of tpls in there that define the layout, and from there you can figure out the css you need to override/change.

Comment: I found the CSS to make it look right in Firefox/Chrome in the calendar_multiday.css but IE still looks like crap.  Do you have any idea on what to change?

Comment: IE is the bain of all our existences when it comes to CSS2 and later so can't offer much assistance there...

Comment: IE needs to follow standards! lol  Thanks for the help though.